# What is the correct file path to use for my <img src="">

Tags: html, image, angular, path, src

I'm learning angular, and in this tutorial on pluralsight, there's a logo.jpg that I want to show up on the welcome page. My current folder structure for the logo is: *src/app/assets/images/logo.jpg*

and for my welcome page it's: *src/app/home/welcome.component.html*

I tried using

```
<img src="./app/assets/images/logo.jpg" />
```

but chrome inspector shows the error

```
GET http://localhost:4200/assets/images/logo.jpg 404 (Not Found)
```

I tried

```
<img src="./src/app/assets/images/logo.jpg" />
<img src="app/assets/images/logo.jpg"/>
<img src="src/app/assets/images/logo.jpg"/>
```

still won't show the image.

I tried

```
<img src="../assets/images/logo.jpg" />
```

to go up one directory, then go into assets, but still doesn't work.

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: That depends on what URLs your server is configured to serve.

Comment: what's the URL of your image? and what's the URL of your HTML file ?

Comment: what's the name of the tutorial?

Comment: @Monkey_Dev1300 I'm learning from the Deborah Kurata's beginner angular course.

Comment: @SLaks how do I find that out? I'm using Visual Studio Code on mac at the moment.

Comment: @MajidLaissi how do I find those out? I'm using visual studio code on mac

Comment: @midnightnoir it's the url that you type in the browser when you get this error. Please add also the path of your actual index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The relative path from your src/index.html is /assets/images. So put:

`<img src="/assets/images/logo.jpg" />`

/assets should stay out of /app. That way, if you build with angular cli they will be added in your /dist folder.

Comment: Nice, it worked! But I'm trying to understand why it worked. my html is under src/app/home and the image is under src/assets/images, how come the relative path we use here didn't become /src/app/assets/images/logo.jpg?

Comment: oh i see, yes, index.html is in /src

Answer (score 0):

try this,

`<img src="image/pradeep.jpg"/>`

here `image` is your folder and image name is `pradeep.jpg`.

Comment: This will work try once(I am using this in my project).-@Vega

Comment: No, it wont even compile. You have placed your images in a wrong place

Comment: Do you want to see the output. I will show you.@Vega